# Why is a provider value in my drawer not updating in real time?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a form called `Forms` that has an `endDrawer`. Inside this form, I am using a `provider` called `GlobalsProvider` that stores all my global variables. One of them is `pendingOutgoingTransactions`, which shows how many pending transactions are stored in [`sqflite`](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) waiting to be sent to SQL Server.

```
class Forms extends StatefulWidget {
  const Forms({super.key});
  @override
  State<Forms> createState() => _FormsState();
}
class _FormsState extends State<Forms> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globals, child) => Scaffold(
          appBar: //...
          endDrawer: Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(flex: 16,
                    child: DrawerHeader(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                const Text('Pending Transactions: ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.grey),),
                                Text(globals.pendingOutgoingTransactions.toString(), style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: //...
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

When I go to another form and write to `sqflite` then hit back to go to `Forms`, this variable correctly increments by 1. I have a timer that fires every 30 seconds to send any pending transactions to SQL Server and, after sending, it decrements the `pendingOutgoingTransactions` variable. This is the part that isn't working right. While I'm on the `Forms` screen, I have the drawer opened and I don't see the value going down. It just stays at 1. Below are the relevant parts of `GlobalsProvider`.

**GlobalsProvider:**

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  Timer? localDBOutgoingStreamTimer; ///Used to continuously send data from localDB to SQL Server
  int pendingOutgoingTransactions = 0;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> writeToLocalDB() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> returnMap = {};

    //...write...

    final physInvRows = await localDBQueryRowCount(table: myTable); //Gets the current number of pending rows
    pendingOutgoingTransactions = physInvRows;

    notifyListeners();

    return returnMap;
  }

  void localDBStartOutgoingStream() {
    localDBOutgoingStreamTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 30), (Timer t) => localDBOutgoingStream());

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void localDBOutgoingStream() async {
    //...send any rows to SQL Server...

    final physInvRowsAfter = await localDBQueryRowCount(table: myTable);

    pendingOutgoingTransactions = physInvRowsAfter;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Login Screen:**

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final globalsClass = GlobalsProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); ///Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose(); ///Run this last
  }

  void initialize() async {
    globalsClass.localDBStartOutgoingStream();

    if (serverList.isNotEmpty) {
      //...runs a function that runs "setState(() {})" at the end
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globals, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: //...
            body: //...
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Main:**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My App',),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Wrapper();
  }
}
```

Comment: When do you call localDBStartOutgoingStream() to initialize the timer

Comment: @EdwynZN on the `initState` of the login screen. Before the user logs in

Comment: Can you provide how you initialize your provider and the login screen init

Comment: @EdwynZN ok I added that. On the login screen, I start the localDBOutgoingStreamTimer in the initialize function. Not sure what you mean by initialize the provider, but I just import it and wrap a `Consumer` widget over my `Scaffold` to start using it

Comment: initialize as in Provider(create: (_) => ..). is your variable globalsClass the same that in your provider? are you sure you're not creating 2 different objects? It seems to me the class in your UI and the one you call in initState are not the same instance, hence why you don't see the timer

Comment: @EdwynZN Ok I added the part where I create `globalsClass` in my `Login` widget. I also added `Main` and `GlobalsProvider`, for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now try this so you're sure its the same object

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); ///Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose(); ///Run this last
  }

  void initialize() async {
    /// initialize the variable here nad use it only here,
    /// I don't know where or how globalsClass is created in your app
    final globalsClass = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context, listen: false);
    globalsClass.localDBStartOutgoingStream();

    if (serverList.isNotEmpty) {
      //...runs a function that runs "setState(() {})" at the end
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globals, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: //...
            body: //...
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh...yea that was it. I guess it was because I was doing `final globalsClass = GlobalsProvider();` instead of doing `final globalsClass = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context, listen: false);`

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!!! I really needed this functionality to work, it was really crucial!!

Comment: I would just add `final` to your `globalsClass` declaration and then this answer is completely right for future readers :)